# Automatic XML corrector

Tags: xml, parsing

In a legacy application which supports plain text templates for information export, I composed a template which exports data into XML. The thing is, that the text information can't be escaped, so I ended up with `<` `>` signs in XML values, and the code I have in .NET throws an exception when parsing the XML.

Is there a way to fix the XML automatically before throwing it to an XML interpreter?

Example:

```
<node>
    Some value which indicates that the quantity < 0.3
</node>
```

The above code should be somehow converted to

```
<node>
    Some value which indicates that the quantity &lt; 0.3
</node>
```

**I am unable to perform this during the export**. What I have is the end XML.

I thought about searching for combinations of `<{node}>` and `</{node}>`, and the ones that don't have a match - to escape. However, the structure can be multi-level, like:

```
<node>
    <data>
    </data>
    <node>
        <data>
        </data>
    </node>
</node>
```

And in that case, what should be used? A regular parser algorithm with tons of procedural code in loops and recursive functions, or some kind of alternative using regular expressions?

Comment: Why is the multilevel a problem for your <{node}> style search? All the tags in the multilevel "match".

Comment: It was a problem coming up with an algorithm which would work in a multi-level node situation. I came up with an idea and trying it out.

Comment: What's multilevel got to do with the problem? as far as you are concerned for this task you have raw text, and <...>  </...> tags.  Newlines are just text.  So if you know the names of the allowed nodes, you should be able to code a regexp to find all "<" signs, and one to find all the "<node" strings, the difference are the places you have to patch.

Comment: I do not know the names of the allowed nodes. Had to come up with something which would detect valid tags without matches, or broken tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically here's what I did:

I composed a regular expression which found possible tags.

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"<(/?)([a-zA-Z]\w*)(?:(?>!<).)*?(/?)>");
```

Having found the matches, I went from one to another, escaping all the text between them.

Using a Stack, I pushed each open tag into it, and popped if the match was for a closing tag. If the popped tag did not correspond - either the opening tag or closing tag is invalid, so I investigated further into the matches, and further down the stack to find which one it actually is.

Sorry for not giving any more code, but it's already on a server which was migrated to the customer. The regular expression was all that I have left of this rushed solution.